# SwiftUi app with 2.0 features runs to iOS, iPadOS but not MacOS

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, cross-platform

I am receiving the following error when running a multi platform SwiftUI app with 2.0 features to a an iMac running Catalina 10.15.7 from XCode 12 beta 4 (12A8179i). The project builds for Mac but fails to run.

dyld: Symbol not found: _$s4Body7SwiftUI3AppPTl
Referenced from: /Users/jamesallison/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CC0_Notes2-bsyhdjklfidgkicvoddwslyeyjia/Build/Products/Debug-maccatalyst/CC0 Notes2.app/Contents/MacOS/CC0 Notes2 (which was built for Mac OS X 14.0)
Expected in: /System/iOSSupport/System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/Versions/A/SwiftUI
in /Users/jamesallison/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CC0_Notes2-bsyhdjklfidgkicvoddwslyeyjia/Build/Products/Debug-maccatalyst/CC0 Notes2.app/Contents/MacOS/CC0 Notes2
[Project Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFSM4.jpg)

The App runs fine to an actual iPhone and an iPad running the latest OS versions. Am I missing something in my settings? Should I be embedding the frameworks? Thanks

(lldb)

Comment: You need macOS 11 (Big-Sur) to run SwiftUI 2.0 application.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar issue with a newly created SwiftUI project, running Xcode 12.2 on macOS 10.15 – it would build fine for iOS and Mac, but I'd get a launch crash with that kind of error when running the Mac version.

I followed the advice in Asperi's comment – upgraded to Big Sur (11.0.1) – and now the Mac version runs fine without that crash.